# How to optimize this SQL Delete statement for faster speed

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

There is a faster way to run this SQL `delete` than this one:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
WHERE TABLE.key NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(MAIN_TABLE.key) FROM MAIN_TABLE)
```

Comment: Hello, the definition of the two involved tables along their indexes and foreign keys might help to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer using `not exists`

```
delete from TABLE t 
 where not exists ( select 0 from MAIN_TABLE m where m.key = t.key )
```

mostly preferable in performance point of view rather than `not in`.

I think this is because

**NOT IN** returns true **for each** non-matched value is found in a subquery, while

**NOT EXISTS** is active only if non-matching row is found within the subquery.

Comment: As long as all key coumns are defined as NOT NULL there should be no difference, both queries should result in the same plan. But if any columns are NULLable NOT EXISTS usually performs better than NOT IN. And the reason is three-valued-logic (NOT IN) vs. two-valued-logic (NOT EXISTS)

Comment: Originally i already thought about having null values , but considering those are keys columns which are expected to be non-null, your idea seems irrelevant for this case @dnoeth . Indeed from this way of think performance shouldnt differ